# Tanspiling & Polyfilling vs browser performance optimizations

Tags: javascript, browser, babeljs

Well, I know we need Transpilers & Pollyfills to keep backward compatibility (in order) at *scale* 
 of

> a syntax updated programming language

or

> new added feature to a pl!

But it raises the question why thers is no an acceptable trade off between the solutions for keeping backward compatibility vs those which aim on advantage of browser performance optimizations; In another word, most of solutions're concentrated to support older browsers with cost of transfering and compiling overheads, rather than exposing a web browser standardization to recommend older browsers to support newer versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most* code a script-writer writes will have next to no impact on the performance of the code running on the user's browser. For any given expensive operation, *usually* there's a clear bottleneck for a few segments of code, which the script-writer can make an attempt to optimize if they wish. Performance optimization is very often possible, and performance bottlenecks *usually* don't have to do with browser incompatibility issues, though they [occasionally do](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/1754), some argue. (RegeneratorRuntime, required for async transpilation, is somewhat heavyweight.)

There is a trade-off involved, but except for RegeneratorRuntime, the difference almost always isn't worth worrying about, I think - there are generally other places in the code you can focus your efforts to make a slow script faster, if that's something you're worried about.

> cost of transfering and compiling overheads

This cost is paid *once*, when the script gets transpiled, and isn't prohibitive, so (many would argue that) it's worth it, in exchange for being able to write in the latest and greatest version of the language, while continuing to allow obsolete browsers to understand your code.

> rather than exposing a web browser standardization to recommend older browsers to support newer versions

Most of those running sufficiently obsolete browsers either don't have a choice (some enterprise environments) or don't really understand computers (else they would have upgraded). Getting them to change is *really hard*.